# Convert ASPX to PDF format

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I have several ASPX web forms which contain all kinds of text boxes, combo boxes, radio button lists, and a lot of other fancy telerik controls. After a form is filled out it needs to be converted to PDF and then printed. I tried wkhtmltopdf but the text boxes in the output were all empty. I have also tried iTextSharp but can't seem to get rid of the InvalidCastException from HTMLWorker.Parse(). I tried the Essential Objects trial version of EO.PDF which worked perfectly except that it would cost lots of money to purchase and probably isn't worth it. I seem to find a lot of examples that are only basic html to pdf converters and won't work with controls. It also seems like many use GridView or similar for iTextSharp, but I don't know much about gridView or if it would help me here.

I need a ideas to try or possibly a solution to my problems with iTextSharp or wkhtmltopdf. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not post your issue with iTextSharp?  That is a solid framework, and you should be able to find someone to help you with it.

Comment: Should I contact SourceForge or iText? Probably iText?

Comment: No, you don't have to contact them--you can get help here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Right. I will ask a more specific question about that but I will leave this up in case anybody gives me better ideas.

Comment: "I tried wkhtmltopdf but the text boxes in the output were all empty" This is probably because you did not keep the values in a place that wkhtmltopdf could use. Does your page show the text box values if you put the same url that you gave to wkhtmltopdf on a random computer? (I mean not the same PC that generated the page on the first place). If it does not, then the problem is in the way you are creating your page and not inside wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I agree, but how would I create the page so that it would show up in the PDF. It seems that the created pdf is the state the page is in on load instead of the state it is in on submit. Is there any way I could make it so that the output pdf is in the state that the page is in on submission? Let me know if what I'm asking isn't clear.

Comment: See my answer on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701409/how-to-use-wkhtmltopdf-converter-with-filled-text-boxes/17708347#17708347).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields are coming out blank because the filled-out information is not part of the HTML structure of the code. The browser shows it, but `wkhtmltopdf` cannot see it.

Easy work-around:

1. On form submission, save the submitted values somewhere.
2. Generate a new HTML page using the same code as the form page.
3. Pre-fill the form's HTML with the values you saved in Step 1. E.g.
   specify the `value` attributes on the form with the submitted data:

   ```
   <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="John Doe">
   ```

`wkhtmltopdf` can now render the form with the values hard-coded in the HTML.

Comment: This solution crossed my mind a few times, but can I generate the second "duplicate" page without loading it in the browser? Since I have about 16 aspx pages I use Redirect.Response("nextpage.aspx") on submission. Also, is there some way to pass the submitted values to the second form without temporarily storing them in a table or anything like that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, you can generate an HTML page without loading it into the browser. Upon form's submission, read the raw HTML file from the disk and process it inside your script.

Comment: As for how to "pass the submitted values to the second form without temporarily storing them", you can keep passing whatever you need as hidden input fields with their values filled out. Keep adding the needed hidden fields on subsequent pages; this way you can daisy-chain the pages together.

Comment: In that case, how would you recommend generating the HTML page? I'm pretty new with ASP.NET, HTML, and Visual Studio in general.

Comment: I have no experience with ASP, but in general terms you need to: (1) read the HTML file from wherever it is, (2) use some kind of an HTML parser to fill in the form values, (3) save the filled-out HTML page, and (4) run `wkhtmltopdf` on this page to generate the PDF.

I believe the hardest part is step (2). In Ruby world, I'd use the Nokogiri library for that. First thing that came up on Google for `asp.net html parser` was [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). There may be native tools in ASP.net to parse HTML &ndash; you have to research into that yourself.